# "3" < "4" evaluates True but "3" < "10" evaluates False. why?

Tags: python

```
print("3" < "10") #This prints False
print("3" < "4") #This prints True
```

How is it possible to compare numbers inside of a string, and why one is True and the other False when in the case of being poissible to compare numbers inside a string both should be True?

I came across this while doing an exercise of progamarcadegames.com and I'm using python 3.3.3 shell

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are comparing **strings**; these are sorted [lexicographically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order).

Since `'1'` comes earlier in the ASCII standard than `'3'`, the string `'10'` is sorted before `'3'` and considered lower, just like 'Martijn' would be sorted before 'Rodrigo' based on the letter 'M'  coming before the letter 'R', but 'jco' would be sorted after 'Martijn' since lowercase characters are listed after uppercase letters in the [ASCII standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=ASCII&oldid=622123651#ASCII_printable_code_chart).

Convert your values to integers if you want to compare them numerically instead.

Comment: I don't know too, you'r answer was exactly what I  was looking for.

Comment: @jco: the order is not alphabetical; lexicographical is not a synonym for alphabetical sorting, although alphabetical sorting is a *form* of lexicographical sorting.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks for the correction. I mentioned alphabetical order because people would have a more direct association, but yeah I see now that it wasn't a good choice.

Comment: @Kay: ick, yes, lowercase letters come after. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 2):

In the question you are comparing two strings as you said yourself. Each string will be compared by ASCII value for each char where `1` in `10` is less than `3`.

```
>>> ord('1')
49
>>> ord('3')
51
>>> ord('4')
52
```

If you need to convert a string to the number you can use `int(str)`:

```
>>> print(int("3") < int("10"))
True
>>> print(int("3") < int("4"))
True
>>>
```

Otherwise you are comparing the string values.

Comment: that does not answer the question

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Quite possibly it answers the question that OP *wanted* to know the answer to. +1

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: Two questions, one in the topic and one in the body. The answer applies to both..

Comment: @Qiau, how exactly does it answer both?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I believe Qiau is referring to *"How is it possible to compare numbers inside of a string?"* from the original question. Personally I would interpret that as asking *why* is it possible to do it. But Qiau's answer is still useful.

Comment: @jco, well the OP has commented on Martijn Pieters answer stating that it has cleared up what he/she was asking so that makes it pretty clear.

Comment: I don't understand how this doesn't answer the question. It's not as complete of an answer as Martijn's, but it still answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

In strings, comparison works from left to right, a character by character, if the characters that are being compared are the same, the next one will be compared

Ex:

"1" will be evaluated less than "3"

Also, "01000" will be less than "1" for the same reason

To compare them as numbers, they must be converted to numbers

Comment: It was already answered, and you didn't cover the important details like Martijn did.

Comment: The answers are seconds apart!

Comment: If someone's answers a more detailed answer that doesn't mean my answer is wrong

Comment: In my view the problem is that I didn't understand a thing on your answer, when i saw your answer(i saw it before the martijn answer) i got even more confused

Comment: @simsim OK then, but I still think Martijn's answer is more useful because it has more details and is better formulated. Yours is correct but confusing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare numbers inside strings, you have to convert them into numbers like this
`int("3")` for example, and then compare their numeric values.